# Deleting a Neo4j node from a Spring application

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm trying to delete a node from an embedded graph.

I'm using SDN 3.3.2.RELEASE and my Neo4j is 2.2.4.

But the node is still around after the repository call:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<null> but was:<Manufacturer [name=Siemens]>
```

Here is my test:

```
  @Test
  public void testDeleteById() {
    Neo4JManufacturer loadedManufacturer = neo4JManufacturerRepository.findOne(manufacturer0.getId());
    assertThatManufacturer(loadedManufacturer).exists();
    neo4JManufacturerRepository.deleteManufacturer(manufacturer0.getId());
    assertThatManufacturer(loadedManufacturer).doesNotExist();
  }
```

The repository is:

```
public interface Neo4JManufacturerRepository extends GraphRepository<Neo4JManufacturer> {
  @Transactional
  @Query("start u = node({id}) match u-[r]-() delete u,r")
  public void deleteManufacturer(@Param("id") Long id);
```

Before trying to delete with the deleteManufacturer() method, I was trying to delete with the delete() method, as in:

```
neo4JManufacturerRepository.delete(manufacturer0.getId());
```

But I would get the exact same test failure:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<null> but was:<Manufacturer [name=Siemens]>
```

This is my node class:

```
@NodeEntity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "id_generator", sequenceName = "sq_id_manufacturer")
public class Neo4JManufacturer extends BaseEntity {

  @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
  @Indexed
  private String name;

  public Neo4JManufacturer() {
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Manufacturer [name=" + name + "]";
  }

}
```

UPDATE:

Following the two comments, I added another find call after the delete call so as to trigger a flush to the data store:

```
Neo4JManufacturer loadedManufacturer = neo4JManufacturerRepository.findOne(manufacturer0.getId());
assertThatManufacturer(loadedManufacturer).exists();
neo4JManufacturerRepository.delete(manufacturer0.getId());
loadedManufacturer = neo4JManufacturerRepository.findOne(manufacturer0.getId());
assertThatManufacturer(loadedManufacturer).doesNotExist();
```

And I also added the optional clause in the query:

```
  @Transactional
  @Query("START u = node({id}) OPTIONAL MATCH u-[r]-() DELETE u,r")
  public void deleteManufacturer(@Param("id") Long id);
```

Now, I get a different error:

```
No primary SDN label exists .. (i.e one starting with _)
```

I suppose the flush after the delete is being attempted, but fails for another reason ?

Also, I wonder if the flushing and transactin behavior is the same when using JPA and when using Neo4j. Indeed the following JPA test works just as expected:

```
  @Test
  public void testDeleteByUserId() {
    User loadedUser = userRepository.findOne(user0.getId());
    assertThatUser(loadedUser).exists();
    loadedUser = userRepository.deleteByUserId(user0.getId());
    loadedUser = userRepository.findOne(user0.getId());
    assertThatUser(loadedUser).doesNotExist();
  }
```

My idea is to do the same with the Neo4j database.

UPDATE: I'm now deleting on a transactional service instead of directly on the repository:

```
  @Modifying
  @Transactional(rollbackFor = EntityNotFoundException.class)
  @Override
  public Neo4JManufacturer delete(Long id) throws EntityNotFoundException {
    Neo4JManufacturer manufacturer = findById(id);
    if (manufacturer == null) {
      throw new EntityNotFoundException();
    } else {
      neo4jManufacturerRepository.delete(manufacturer.getId());
      return manufacturer;
    }
  }
```

The service is called like:

```
  @Test
  public void testDeleteById() {
    Neo4JManufacturer loadedManufacturer = neo4JManufacturerRepository.findOne(manufacturer0.getId());
    assertThatManufacturer(loadedManufacturer).exists();
    neo4JManufacturerService.delete(manufacturer0.getId());
    Neo4JManufacturer anotherManufacturer = neo4JManufacturerRepository.findOne(manufacturer0.getId());
    assertThatManufacturer(anotherManufacturer).doesNotExist();
  }
```

But I still get the same exception:

```
testDeleteById(it.kahoot.robot.data.neo4j.Neo4JManufacturerRepositoryTest)  Time elapsed: 0.137 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No primary SDN label exists .. (i.e one starting with _) ; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary SDN label exists .. (i.e one starting with _) 
        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.LabelBasedNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy.readAliasFrom(LabelBasedNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy.java:136)
        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.LabelBasedNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy.readAliasFrom(LabelBasedNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy.java:40)
        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.TRSTypeAliasAccessor.readAliasFrom(TRSTypeAliasAccessor.java:36)
        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.TRSTypeAliasAccessor.readAliasFrom(TRSTypeAliasAccessor.java:26)
        at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.readType(DefaultTypeMapper.java:102)
```

UPDATE II: I have now a test that passes fine and behaves as expected. Still the test is under a @Transactional annotation. And it does not do any manual flush. The interesting part, and the reason the test stopped giving the error:

```
No primary SDN label exists .. (i.e one starting with _)
```

is that the findById or findOne calls were replaced by a findByName call. Doing either a findById or findOne call would trigger the above error.

Here is how the working test looks like:

```
  @Test
  public void testIsDelete() {
    Neo4JManufacturer loadedManufacturer = neo4JManufacturerRepository.findOne(manufacturer0.getId());
    assertThatManufacturer(loadedManufacturer).exists();
    neo4JManufacturerRepository.delete(manufacturer0.getId());
    loadedManufacturer = neo4JManufacturerService.findByName(loadedManufacturer.getName());
    assertThatManufacturer(loadedManufacturer).doesNotExist();
  }
```

The repository findByName is:

```
  Neo4JManufacturer findByName(String name);
```

I had a logger in place which showed the id being set above 0

```
DEBUG  [Neo4JManufacturerRepositoryTest] ==========>> Id: 4 Name: Siemens
```

Still, using a findById instead of a findByName was giving the above error.

And I wonder why.

UPDATE III:

I have now removed the transactional annotation from the test.

Here is the test:

```
  @Test
  public void testDelete() {
    Neo4JManufacturer loadedManufacturer = neo4JManufacturerRepository.findOne(manufacturer0.getId());
    assertThatManufacturer(loadedManufacturer).exists();
    neo4JManufacturerRepository.delete(manufacturer0.getId());
    loadedManufacturer = neo4JManufacturerRepository.findOne(manufacturer0.getId());
    assertThatManufacturer(loadedManufacturer).doesNotExist();
    assertThatManufacturer(manufacturer0).exists();
    manufacturer0 = neo4JManufacturerRepository.save(manufacturer0);
  }
```

The console says:

```
2016-09-01 14:45:57,769 DEBUG [main] c.t.d.n.Neo4JManufacturerRepositoryTest ==========>> Before - Created manufacturer0 - Id: 0
 2016-09-01 14:45:58,127 DEBUG [main] c.t.d.n.Neo4JManufacturerRepositoryTest ==========>> After - Deleted manufacturer0 - Id: 0
 2016-09-01 14:45:58,320 DEBUG [main] c.t.d.n.Neo4JManufacturerRepositoryTest ==========>> Before - Created manufacturer0 - Id: 4
 2016-09-01 14:45:58,850 DEBUG [main] c.t.d.n.Neo4JManufacturerRepositoryTest ==========>> After - Deleted manufacturer0 - Id: 4
 2016-09-01 14:45:59,035 DEBUG [main] c.t.d.n.Neo4JManufacturerRepositoryTest ==========>> Before - Created manufacturer0 - Id: 8
 Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 23.625 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.thalasoft.data.neo4j.Neo4JManufacturerRepositoryTest
testDelete(com.thalasoft.data.neo4j.Neo4JManufacturerRepositoryTest)  Time elapsed: 0.334 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.dao.DataRetrievalFailureException: Node 8 not found; nested exception is org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: Node 8 not found
```

It errors on the last source code line of the test, the one doing the save() operation.

Why does it look for a node ? Why does it complain it is not found ? Shouldn't it be not found since I'm trying to create it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the same transaction the node is still visible, and as your test is very probably @Transactional per method, the tx is only finished (rolled back) after the method finishes

see: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/transactions-delete.html

If you add a transactional handling (commit) after the delete without having the @Transactional on top of your test. You should not be able to see the node anymore.

### Update

I ran your test, it is as I explained.

Your test (via its superclass) had a @Transactional annotation, so that all operations within the test method are executed in *one* transaction and afterwards rolled back.

If you want to see the real world behavior the deletion would have to happen in it's own tx (as part of your service call) after that transaction is finished, the node is no longer visible.

Also your assert tested that the previously loaded node would be null, which is never the case because the already existing variable is not changed as part of your delete operation.

I removed the global @Transactional annotation from your test-superclass and changed the test method to this:

```
  @Test
  public void testDeleteById() {
    Neo4JManufacturer loadedManufacturer = neo4JManufacturerRepository.findOne(manufacturer0.getId());
    assertThatManufacturer(loadedManufacturer).exists();

    neo4JManufacturerService.delete(manufacturer0.getId());

    loadedManufacturer = neo4JManufacturerRepository.findOne(manufacturer0.getId());
// both would work
//    loadedManufacturer = neo4JManufacturerService.findById(manufacturer0.getId());
    assertThatManufacturer(loadedManufacturer).doesNotExist();
  }
```

Now it passes and exhibits the expected behavior: after the tx with the delete is completed the node is gone.

Comment: What if I add a     loadedManufacturer = neo4JManufacturerRepository.findOne(manufacturer0.getId());
 before my assertThatManufacturer call ? Shouldn't that trigger a flush to the data store ?

Comment: I see two issues here, which may be one and the same. Even deleting through a transactional service does not delete (expected:<null> but was:<Manufacturer [name=Siemens]>). And doing a second loadedManufacturer = neo4JManufacturerRepository.findOne(manufacturer0.getId()) right after the delete gives a Neo4j error (No primary SDN label exists .. (i.e one starting with _))

Comment: Could it be that the CRUD delete only deletes the _ label ?

Comment: After the transaction is committed, if you reload the data you should be seeing that it is gone.

Comment: I heartily agree, but as stated in my above comment, doing a second findOne gives me an error. Or do you mean something else altogether with reloading the data...

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow right now there is too much detail, and I'm not sure about the actual question :) It would be cool if you could set up a minimal project on github that reproduces the issue with a quick description in the readme.

Comment: Hi, I have created a minimal project on github at https://github.com/stephaneeybert/neo4j-issue Let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the project. It is as I explained in my answer. I add an update section.

Comment: I'm still trying to find a way while keeping the @Transactional-ity of the test. Following this article http://www.marcobehler.com/2014/06/25/should-my-tests-be-transactional/ I tried adding a entityManager.flush(); right after the delete call, but it changed nothing. Since the exact same test design works in the JPA world, I wonder if the two transaction managers have the same behavior.

Comment: I added an update to the question as I got my test to pass fine. It required replacing the findById and findOne by a findByName call. Would you have an idea why is that ?

Comment: Hi Michael, I'm coming back to Neo4j and now trying to fix this old issue following your advice to remove the transactional annotation from the test. I added an Update III in my question describing what is going on.

Comment: Indeed, all 3 method calls to `findOne` or `findById` or `findByName` work fine. One last thing that was failing my test was that I was doing a `save` on this entity that had been deleted. But the object still had the original id. It appeared that the framework attempted to load the object before saving it, and was failing at loading time. Nullifying the id before saving the entity resolved this last issue: `manufacturer0.setId(null);`

Answer (score 2):

Since your Cypher query is using `MATCH u-[r]-()`, it will fail if the specified node does not participate in any relationships.

You should use `OPTIONAL MATCH` instead, which allows the query to succeed even if the specified node does not participate in any relationships:

```
"START u = node({id}) OPTIONAL MATCH u-[r]-() DELETE u,r"
```